# iOS encryption to NSData with key identifier

Tags: objective-c, ios, encryption, aes, nsdata

In my iOS4+ project iam using AES 128 encryption to encrypt some large strings which are then sent to a php server. Encryption is done using one of the provided AES128 keys (which is randomly selected). When i encrypt the data i get NSData.

What i need is to add a 2 bytes of some kind of identificator of the key in the begining of the file im sending to that server so that server will be able to identificate the key i used for encryption. How can i do this (appending 2 bytes to nsdata)? And what exactly can i use as this identificator?

Thanks in an advanced! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would obviously need to hard code or share in another request the dictionary what links and identifier to a key but i'll let you do that...

to append some identifiers, for example two digits

```
    ...

    const Byte identifierBytes[2] = { 0xFF, 0xAA }; //two identifier bytes

    NSMutableData *dataToSendToServer = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithBytes:identifierBytes length:2];
    [dataToSendToServer appendData:encryptedDataToSendToServer];

    //send the dataToSendToServer to the server...

    ...
```

Then to read the identifier on the app side...

```
    ...

    const Byte *identifierBytes = [[dataFromTheServer subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2)] bytes];
    if (identifierBytes[0] == 0xFF && identifierBytes[1] == 0xAA) {

        //the bytes are for the identifier {0xFF,0xAA}
        NSData *encryptedDataFromServer = [dataFromTheServer subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, dataFromTheServer.length - 2)];

    }

    ...
```

You might want to check it over as its written from memory but you should be able to get the idea

Answer (score 0):

If your key index won't change, why not using the key index in your key-array as the identification?

You can add bytes like this:

```
NSMutableData *mutableData = [yourNSData mutableCopy]; // make a mutable copy so you can append bytes.
int aIndex = 0; // example index
[mutableData appendBytes:aIndex length:sizeof(int)]; // append a 4byte int 32
```

You can then unpack the int in PHP.